# How to forcibly switch Geth to follow other chain and not the largest?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain-fork

During the previous fork on Ropstan, my node seems to follow to the wrong chain if I understood correctly. As for now, it's on 6537730, it's the longest but major players are around 6523511. What are the necessary steps to follow in order to fix it?

How it's selected by default? and how should I override it if the criteria will point again to the wrong chain due to hash power or else?

Comment: You will find an example twitter by a go-ethereum developer https://twitter.com/peter_szilagyi/status/1178634327518781441: `--whitelist=6485846=0x43f0cd1e5b1f9c4d5cda26c240b59ee4f1b510d0a185aa8fd476d091b0097a80`